# How to Open JQM Popup After Clicking Parent Element

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to open a jQueryMobile Popup (the child div's) with the following HTML layout ...

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child" data-role="popup">Foo</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
 <div class="child" data-role="popup">Bar</div>
</div>
```

Here's the script that I'm using to open the popup's when the user clicks in a parent div. I cannot figure out not only why this script doesn't work, but also how to open the popup's.

```
$(".parent").click(function () {
   $(this).children(".child").popup("open");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when jQM 'enhances' the popup, it removes it from the parent DIV and creates a .ui-popup-container DIV at the same level as the content DIV. Because of this relying on a common class name for the popups won't work.

You need to somehow indicate which parent each child belongs to. You could use id's or a data-attribute, etc.

[image]

Here is an example using data-attributes:

```
    <div class="parent" id="parent1">
        <div class="child" data-role="popup" data-parentid="parent1">
            <p>Foo</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent" id="parent2">
        <div class="child" data-role="popup" data-parentid="parent2">
            <p>Bar</p>
        </div>
    </div>

$('.parent').on("click", function () {        
    var id = $(this).prop("id");
    $('[data-role="popup"]').each(function(){
        var pid = $(this).jqmData("parentid");
        if (id == pid){
             $(this).popup("open");
        }
    });
});
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/rxLxzytk/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child" data-role="popup">Foo</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
 <div class="child" data-role="popup">Bar</div>
</div>

    $('.parent').click(function() {
        $(this).find('.child').popup("open");
    });
```